# Show if $f\colon A\to B$ is surjective and $H\subseteq B$ then $f(f^{-1}(H))=H$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm supposed to show that if $f\colon A\to B$ is surjective and $H\subseteq B$ then $f(f^{-1}(H))=H$.

I have managed to show that $f(f^{-1}(H))\subseteq H$ but I am really struggling to show that $H\subseteq f(f^{-1}(H)$. Is it easier to prove this dealing with sets or an element of a set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let $h \in H$. Then since $f$ is surjective, there is some $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = h$. Then $a \in f^{-1}(H)$, so...

Comment: Does $a\in f^{-1}(H)$ follow from the fact that $f(a)=h$ so then $a=f^{-1}(h)\in f^{-1}(H)$ but this implies that the function is injective doesn't it?

Comment: @NadiaKim: yes, $a \in f^{-1}(h)$ precisely means $f(a) \in H$, so that's correct. No, this does not imply $f$ is injective. Do you recall the definition of an injective function? A function is *injective* if $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $x = y$ (in other words, different inputs map to different outputs). Where do you see that coming up here?

Comment: For some reason it has been ingrained that in order to multiply by the inverse when doing these proofs the function must be injective. I'm guessing this is incorrect?

Comment: @NadiaKim: you're not multiplying by an inverse. The inverse image $f^{-1}(H)$ is the set of all elements of $A$ whose image lies in $H$ under $f$. The statement $f(a) = h$ for $h \in H$ indicates that the image of $a$ under $f$ lies in $H$, so $a \in f^{-1}(H)$. The surjectivity of $f$ allows us to find such an $a$ for each $h \in H$. IS this clearer?

Comment: Yea that definitely makes sense to me now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When $b\in f(f^{-1}H)$ then exists $p\in f^{-1}H$ such that $f(p)=b$, but $f(p)\in H$ that is $b\in H$.

Then $f(f^{-1}H)\subset H$.

Now if $c\in H$ then by surjectivity exists $q\in A$ such that $f(q)=c$ that is $f(q)\in H$, so $q\in f^{-1}(c)\subseteq f^{-1}H$ then $f(q)\in f(f^{-1}H)$ that is $c\in f(f^{-1}H)$.

Then $H\subset f(f^{-1}H)$.